# Make a real time plot (like a movie) for the next code? How to parallelize the code for use my GPU?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, matlab-figure

I have the next code, wich solves a Schnakenberg model, but I have to press enter every time the "if" condition is false, what I want and I don't know how to do it, is to remove the "if" sentence in the code and see the plot in real time and see the movement of the plot in real time and add a colorbar in the right side of the plot.

Is there any way to do this?.

```
%Solve a Turing model system of equations in 2-D space over time. Apply
%Euler’s Method to a semi-discretized Reaction-Diffusion system.
%clear all
%Grid size
Tf=1000000;
a=-1; % Lower boundary
b=1; % Upper boundary
M=50; % M is the number of spaces between points a and b.
dx=0.04; %(b-a)/M; % dx is delta x
dy=0.04; %(b-a)/M;
x=linspace(a,b,M+1); % M+1 equally spaced x vectors including a and b.
y=linspace(a,b,M+1);
%Time stepping
dt=0.08; %100*(dx^2)/2; % dt is delta t the time step
N=Tf/dt; % N is the number of time steps in the interval [0,1]
%Constant Values
D=0.516; % D is the Diffusion coefficient Du/Dv
delta=0.0021; % sizes the domain for particular wavelengths
alpha=0.899; % a is alpha, a coefficient in f and g (-a is gamma)
beta=-0.91; % b is beta, another coefficient in f and g
r1=3.5; % r1 is the cubic term
r2=0; % r2 is the quadratic term
gamma=-alpha; % g is for gamma
%pre-allocation
unp1=zeros(M+3,M+3);
vnp1=zeros(M+3,M+3);
%Initial Conditions
un=-0.5+rand(M+3,M+3); %Begin with a random point between [-0.5,0.5]
vn=-0.5+rand(M+3,M+3);
for n=1:N
for i=2:M+2
un(i,1)=un(i,3); %Boundary conditions on left flux is zero
un(i,M+3)=un(i,M+1); %Boundary conditions on right
vn(i,1)=vn(i,3);
vn(i,M+3)=vn(i,M+1);
end
for j=2:M+2
un(1,j)=un(3,j); %Boundary conditions on left
un(M+3,j)=un(M+1,j); %Boundary conditions on right
vn(1,j)=vn(3,j);
vn(M+3,j)=vn(M+1,j);
end
for i=2:M+2
for j=2:M+2
%Source function for u and v
srcu=alpha*un(i,j)*(1-r1*vn(i,j)^2)+vn(i,j)*(1-r2*un(i,j));
srcv=beta*vn(i,j)*(1+(alpha*r1/beta)*un(i,j)*vn(i,j))+un(i,j)*(gamma+r2*vn(i,j));
uxx=(un(i-1,j)-2*un(i,j)+un(i+1,j))/dx^2; %Laplacian u
vxx=(vn(i-1,j)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i+1,j))/dx^2; %Laplacian v
uyy=(un(i,j-1)-2*un(i,j)+un(i,j+1))/dy^2; %Laplacian u
vyy=(vn(i,j-1)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i,j+1))/dy^2; %Laplacian v
Lapu=uxx+uyy;
Lapv=vxx+vyy;
unp1(i,j)=un(i,j)+dt*(D*delta*Lapu+srcu);
vnp1(i,j)=vn(i,j)+dt*(delta*Lapv+srcv);
end
end
un=unp1;
vn=vnp1;
% Graphing
if mod(n,2)==0
%subplot(2,1,2)
hdl = surf(x,y,un(2:M+2,2:M+2));
set(hdl,'edgecolor','none');
axis([ -1, 1,-1,1]);
%caxis([-10,15]);
view(2);
colorbar;
fprintf('Time t = %f\n',n*dt);
ch = input('Hit enter to continue :','s');
if (strcmp(ch,'k') == 1)
keyboard;
end
end
end
```

Also, I want to parallelize this code in order to use my GPU, some other people told me that I have to vectorice the code and substitute this parts:

```
for i=2:M+2
    un(i,1)=un(i,3); %Boundary conditions on left flux is zero
    un(i,M+3)=un(i,M+1); %Boundary conditions on right
    vn(i,1)=vn(i,3);
    vn(i,M+3)=vn(i,M+1);
end
```

Insteado of:

```
i=2:M+2
un(i,1)=un(i,3); %Boundary conditions on left flux is zero
un(i,M+3)=un(i,M+1); %Boundary conditions on right
vn(i,1)=vn(i,3);
vn(i,M+3)=vn(i,M+1);
```

And replace for this in my code:

```
i=2:M+2;
j=2:M+2;
srcu=alpha*un(i,j).*(1-r1*vn(i,j)^2)+vn(i,j).*(1-r2*un(i,j));
srcv=beta*vn(i,j).*(1+(alpha*r1/beta)*un(i,j).*vn(i,j))+un(i,j).*(gamma+r2*vn(i,j));
uxx=(un(i-1,j)-2*un(i,j)+un(i+1,j))/dx^2; %Laplacian u
vxx=(vn(i-1,j)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i+1,j))/dx^2; %Laplacian v
uyy=(un(i,j-1)-2*un(i,j)+un(i,j+1))/dy^2; %Laplacian u
vyy=(vn(i,j-1)-2*vn(i,j)+vn(i,j+1))/dy^2; %Laplacian v
```

And actually I've done that, but the big question is how to call the "par" functions or how the code will be at the end in order to make it faster and in parallel.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Once you have done this replacement, you only need one loop, the outer loop over n. This one you can probably not replace, as it depends on previous iterations.  With the replacement of the inner for loops, your code will run parallel. If you want GPU execution, just cast the respective variables as GPU arrays instead.

Comment: @FelixDarvas That is what I just don't understand. I should separate this part of the code and call it later?

Comment: @FelixDarvas How the code finally look like? I mean, that is the parallelization thing that I just don't understand.

Comment: take a look at the code examples above, i.e. the 2nd snippet you posted. If you replace the for i=2:M+2 ... end loop with just the content of the loop and set i=2:M+2, as shown in the 3rd snippet, Matlab will compute e.g. un and vn for all i=2,3, .., M+2. Generally, you can manipulate whole vectors or matrices in matlab, without referencing explicitly individual elements.